# populating combobox in dijit using json file retrived using dojo.xhrGet

Tags: dojo

i am working on dojo and i am a beginer. well, i want to create a Create a dojo ItemFileReadStore using the data retrived from a json file using ajax (dojo.xhrGet) , which can be used to populate the combo box. i tried working on it , but no success ! can anyone please guide me through how i can call the json file and then use the data to populate the combobox !

```
var _getPlacetypes = function(){
        dojo.xhrGet({
            url: "place_types.json",
            handleAs: "json",
            timeout: 5000,
            load: function(response, args) {
                console.log(response);

            },
            error: function(error_msg,details) {
                PropertyMap.handleError(error_msg, details);
            }
        });
    }

    var myStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        jsId:data,
        url: "place_types.json",
        });
```

i am using something like this ! is it the right way ?

thanks

regards !

Answer (score 2):

Define the structure of you data first.

`var myData = {
identifier: 'id',
label: 'My Label',
items: []
};`

The `identifier` must uniquely identify each row.

You must use an ItemFileWriteStore (not ItemFileReadStore) since you want to populate it using the response from ajax.

`var myStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: myData});`

Assuming that `response` is a json containing `someList` which has objects with `id`, 
do this inside `load:` -

```
load: function(response, args) {
    dojo.forEach(response.someList, 
        function(oneItem, i) {
        myStore.newItem({oneItem.id : oneItem.id});
    });

    myStore.save();
}
```

This way you can populate the data store from the json response.

While creating the ComboBox, you should give the store as `myStore`.

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox({
        id: "stateSelect",
        store: myStore,
    }, "stateSelect");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [JsonRestStore](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/data/JsonRestStore) to simplify your code a bit?

You may have a reason for for using xhrGet directly but I think if not you would find JsonRestStore to be a great asset in your work